# How to filter array of objects and get distinct based on a specific property

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've got the following array that I want to filter based on one property and get distinct from another property. I managed to get it working but is there a much cleaner way to achieve this?

```js
var result = [{
    "Class": "Class C",
    "Group": "Group A",
    "Value": 1
  },
  {
    "Class": "Class C",
    "Group": "Group A",
    "Value": 2
  },
  {
    "Class": "Class A",
    "Group": "Group B",
    "Value": 2
  },
  {
    "Class": "Class C",
    "Group": "Group B",
    "Value": 10
  }
];

result = result.reduce((x, {
  Class,
  Group,
  Value
}) => {
  Class.includes("Class C") && x.push({
    Class,
    Group,
    Value
  });
  return x;
}, []);
console.log(result);

result = [...new Map(result.map(item => [item["Group"], item])).values()];
console.log("Expected Result:");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two tasks, filtering, and finding distinct items (practically: grouping).

So when we define two functions, one for filtering by a given property:

```
const filterByProp = 
    (prop) =>
        (value) =>
            (items) =>
                items.filter((item) => item[prop] === value);
```

and one for finding the distinct (in this case: each first item per value) by a given property:

```
const distinctByProp = 
    (prop) =>
        (items) =>
            Object.values(items.reduce((group, item) => {
                if (!group.hasOwnProperty(item[prop])) group[item[prop]] = item;
                return group;
            }, {}));
```

we can do

```
const onlyClassC = filterByProp("Class")("Class C");
const distinctByGroup = distinctByProp("Group");

const filtered = distinctByGroup(onlyClassC(result));
```

and get `filtered` as:

```
[
  {
    "Class": "Class C",
    "Group": "Group A",
    "Value": 1
  },
  {
    "Class": "Class C",
    "Group": "Group B",
    "Value": 10
  }
]
```

If you want the last item per distinct group instead of the first, remove the `if (!group.hasOwnProperty(item[prop]))` from `distinctByProp`.

```js
const filterByProp = 
    (prop) =>
        (value) =>
            (items) =>
                items.filter((item) => item[prop] === value);

const distinctByProp = 
    (prop) =>
        (items) =>
            Object.values(items.reduce((group, item) => {
                if (!group.hasOwnProperty(item[prop])) group[item[prop]] = item;
                return group;
            }, {}));

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
const onlyClassC = filterByProp("Class")("Class C");
const distinctByGroup = distinctByProp("Group");

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
var result = [
  {
    "Class": "Class C",
    "Group": "Group A",
    "Value": 1
  },
  {
    "Class": "Class C",
    "Group": "Group A",
    "Value": 2
  },
  {
    "Class": "Class A",
    "Group": "Group B",
    "Value": 2
  },
  {
    "Class": "Class C",
    "Group": "Group B",
    "Value": 10
  }
];

const filtered = distinctByGroup(onlyClassC(result));
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Yup, this would do! Thanks.

Comment: @nadz There are a many libraries that supply the two helper functions that I wrote myself here, among others, so that you would be left with implementing the "we can do" block only. Some of them are more "functional programming"-minded, some take a more traditional approach, have a look around - it's not always worth it to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I'll do some digging. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @nadz, why do you accept this answer even the expected output is not the same as you suggest? Just curious.

Comment: With the more "functional programming" approach that I took above, you get higher function reusability and composability, i.e. you can make a function `filterByClass = filterByProp("Class")`, and keep it around, and specialize it for the filter value only when needed, or you could use it to do filtering elsewhere.

Comment: @ikhvjs The OP's code works with the order the array is iterated in, so does mine. No explicit sorting happens in either solution, and without any clear definition of what's correct, it's pointless to explicitly implement a sort order. If a certain order is required, the input can easily be sorted before filtering using `Array#sort`. This also works nicely with the *"each first item per value"* semantics of my `distinctByProp()` function.

Comment: @Tomalak, The ```Map Object``` in OP's question takes the last occurrence object as output. I thought that is his intention in the begining.

Comment: @ikhvjs But that's an implementation detail of the `Map` object - a side-effect, not something one should rely on. So I took it as purely circumstantial to the OP's use of the `Map` object to tackle the issue, not as the intention, and left a *"If you want the last item per distinct group instead of the first..."* hint below my code.

Comment: @Tomalak, I just saw this ```If you want the last item per distinct group instead of the first...``` Sorry. my fault.

Comment: @ikhvjs No worries, the way I see it we were just discussing the issue. Picking the opposite result order was actually intentional on my part to probe whether the OP had a hidden intention there or not.

Comment: Good to hear. Your solution is indeed more competent.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the most efficient way but more clean codes only.

```js
const result = [
  { Class: "Class C", Group: "Group A", Value: 1 },
  { Class: "Class C", Group: "Group A", Value: 2 },
  { Class: "Class A", Group: "Group B", Value: 2 },
  { Class: "Class C", Group: "Group B", Value: 10 },
];

const output = result
  .filter(obj => obj.Class.includes("Class C"))
  .reverse()
  .filter(
    (obj, i, arr) => i === arr.findIndex(obj2 => obj.Group === obj2.Group)
  )
  .reverse();
  
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is necessarily better than yours, but it employs a few different approaches. Namely, sorting the data first so you don't have to query to find the largest value and filtering first to get rid of dupes.

```
let classFilter = "Class C", filtered = 
  // We're making an object that should be delivered as an array
  Object.values(result  
     // first sort by value so when we filter, we capture the highest if there are duplicates
     .sort((a, b) => (a.Value < b.Value) ? 1 : -1)
     // filter out any duplicates of our target classFilter
     .filter(e => e.Class === classFilter)
     // get unique only Groups
     .reduce((b, a) => {
        if (!b.hasOwnProperty(a.Group)) b[a.Group] = a;
        return b;
     }, {})
  )
```

```js
let result = [{
    "Class": "Class C",
    "Group": "Group A",
    "Value": 1
  },
  {
    "Class": "Class C",
    "Group": "Group A",
    "Value": 2
  },
  {
    "Class": "Class A",
    "Group": "Group B",
    "Value": 2
  },
  {
    "Class": "Class C",
    "Group": "Group B",
    "Value": 10
  }
];

let classFilter = "Class C"

let filtered = Object.values(result.sort((a, b) => (a.Value < b.Value) ? 1 : -1).filter(e => e.Class === classFilter).reduce((b, a) => {
  if (!b.hasOwnProperty(a.Group)) b[a.Group] = a;
  return b;
}, {}))
console.log(filtered)
```